# Terminate ng serve task in vs code on stop debugging

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have an Angular project and currently debugging inside vs code via debugger for chrome. My `launch.json` uses `"preLaunchTask": "serve"` where serve is defined in `tasks.json` as `"ng serve"` so that I have "ng serve" executed first and sever is ready before browser is opened by debugger to hit http://localhost:4200.

Everything works fine. However, when I stop debugging, I still have `"ng serve"` task running as expected and I have to terminate that task manually every time.

I tried to use `"postDebugTask"` in `launch.json` but not much luck as vs code will complain about starting a new task (postDebug) until another running task (preLaunch) is not terminated. Could anyone please help?

Comment: [Here's a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60330174/9925593)

Answer (score 5):

After looking into this for a while, there doesn't seem to be any clean way to kill a task in VS Code that was kicked off as part of `preBuildTask`. It's a build task, and the debug task itself appears to be separate from that. Since the debug PID itself is targeted at Chrome, there's a weird separation between the two.

So, let's brute force it.

First, we need to get our initial `ng serve` running as a child process so another task won't complain about the first task hogging the terminal. This task worked for me:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "serve",
            "command": "ng serve",
            "isBackground": true,
            "type": "shell",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation": "relative",
                "background": {
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note the `isBackground` property. This will spawn any future tasks in their own shell. `presentation` is `reveal: always` so we can see the CLI output. We can get fancy and capture CLI problems with the debug process in `problemMatcher`, but let's forget it for now.

Now, let's make a `kill` task. Instead of working through VS Code to find the initial spawned task, let's do it through our OS. Now this is highly dependent on **which OS** and **which shell** you use (shells can be configured per task via the `shell` property).

We need to find the PID of the `ng serve` shell and send it off to the big computer in the sky. We can look for the PID hogging the localhost port being served against, which I'll assume is 4200 by default.

Example **CMD** command:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %A in ('"netstat -a -n -o | find 4200""') DO ('"Taskill /PID %E /F"')
```

Example **bash/terminal** command (simpler, as usual):

```
[sudo] lsof -ti:4200 | xargs kill
```

Then just make a `kill` task with the command and add it to `postDebugTask`:

```
    {
        "label": "kill",
        "command": "lsof -ti:4200 | xargs kill",
        "type": "shell",
    }
```

If you run into access rights, you can probably fix it by running VS Code as admin or by providing a path to an .exe where you already have admin rights. Again, depends on your shell and OS.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in [this S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54484341/5490505), the ability to run workbench commands from tasks was recently added to VSCode. It appears as though the best solution to this problem is to run the following task `"postDebugTask": "end serve"`

```
{
   "label": "end serve",
   "type": "process",
   "command":[
      "${command:workbench.action.tasks.terminate}"
   ],
},
```

This will prompt you to select the task you want to terminate from a drop down list. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to tell VSCode what task you want to terminate via an argument.

As pointed out in the linked answer, if you only have one task to choose from, you can automatically select that task with

```
{
   "label": "end serve",
   "type": "process",
   "command":[
      "${command:workbench.action.tasks.terminate}",
      "${command:workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem}",
   ],
},
```

Thus eliminating the drop down menu.

Answer (score 3):

This should work out, tested on Windows.
Comments in code.

File: `launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            //I use MS Edge to debug because is the only browser I dont use
            "type": "pwa-msedge",

            //For launch to work alongside "userDataDir", the browser has to be closed (no instances running)
            "request": "launch",

            //Before start the debugger, start the application
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",

            "name": "Debug Application X",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",

            //This key open the browser with default user profile loaded (in particular, extensions)
            //I use this because I need a modify HTTP header extension
            //If you dont need any extension, just remove this line and the restriction of
            //no instances running does not apply anymore
            "userDataDir": false,

            //Task to kill the application
            "postDebugTask": "end all",
        }
    ]
}
```

File: `tasks.json`

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        //Task to start application
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "start",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "typescript",
                "pattern": "$tsc",
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": true,
                    "beginsPattern": {
                        "regexp": "(.*?)"
                    },
                    "endsPattern": {
                        "regexp": "bundle generation complete"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        //Task to end application
        //Be aware that this task will end ALL the tasks running in VS Code
        {
            "label": "end all",
            "command": "echo ${input:terminate}",
            "type": "shell",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        //Input to pass the argument terminateAll to workbench.terminate
        {
            "id": "terminate",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "workbench.action.tasks.terminate",
            "args": "terminateAll"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old issue, but still lives on in mid 2022 ... for a quick and dirty way to terminate the ng serve, you can click in code's terminal tab and hit `<ctrl-c>`.  This is not what the OP asked for, but for others seeking a quick workaround, this may help and is faster than `ps` / `kill`.