VSCode: How to configure tasks to open browser after server task is ready
I am writing documentation on my project using mkdocs. I would like to automatically run mkdocs serve (compiles the docs and runs local web server) and open browser window(simpleBrowser.show).
The first part is quite easy.
Opening the browser window at the right time isn't.
If I let the browser open immediately, the server isn't ready yet and nothing gets displayed.
If I make the browser depend on the server, it never opens because server never finishes. The server needs to keep running.
If I kill the server manually, browser window will open, but again, display nothing, since the server isn't running anymore.
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Server",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "mkdocs serve",
        "group": "none",
        "presentation": {
          "reveal": "silent",
          "panel": "new"
        },
      },
      {
        "label": "Open browser in panel",
        "command": "${input:openSimpleBrowser}",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "runOptions": {
          "runOn": "folderOpen"
        },
        "dependsOrder": "sequence",
        "dependsOn": ["Server"]
      }
    ],
    "inputs": [
      {
          "id": "openSimpleBrowser",
          "type": "command",
          "command": "simpleBrowser.show",
          "args": [
              "http://localhost:8000"
          ]
      }
  ]
  }

I also tried adding problem matching to the Server task. That didn't change anything.
        "problemMatcher":[
          {
            "base": "$tsc",
            "background": {
              "activeOnStart": true,
              "beginsPattern":"Building documentation",
              "endsPattern":"Serving"
            },
          }

As far as I can tell, these patterns should match on the server output, but no luck.

out of curiosity, is the server outputting those messages to stdout or stderr? (not that I know whether it makes a difference). what if you follow the shape of the compound task in the docs?

also, what if you add isBackground? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527723/11107541

The changes suggested by super-starball-ultra helped. It needed both isBackground: true and third task to chain the other 2 together.
Final working script is:
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Server",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "mkdocs serve",
      "group": "none",
      "isBackground": true,
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent",
        "panel": "new"
      },
      "problemMatcher":[
        {
          "base": "$tsc",
          "background": {
            "activeOnStart": true,
            "beginsPattern":"Building documentation",
            "endsPattern":"Serving"
          },
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Open browser in panel",
      "command": "${input:openSimpleBrowser}",
    },
    {
      "label": "Run everything",
      "dependsOn":["Server", "Open browser in panel"],
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      }
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
        "id": "openSimpleBrowser",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "simpleBrowser.show",
        "args": [
            "http://localhost:8000"
        ]
    }
  ]
}

