# How to make vscode stop both nodemon and npm after stopping the debugger?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

I'm running the following launch.json configuration and package.json script and it's working very well, I'm able to run the app and debug it. However, when I hit the "stop" button in the vscode debugger, nodemon is stopped but the npm process (and the entire app) keeps running. If I modify a file and save it then nodemon comes back up again (as expected). The only way to really stop the app is to hit ctrl+c in the terminal. Is there a way to stop both processes once the debugger stop button is clicked?

**package.json script**

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "node app",
 "debug": "nodemon --experimental-modules --inspect ./bin/www.mjs"
}
```

**launch.json config**

```
{
 "type": "node",
 "request": "launch",
 "name": "Launch via NPM",
 "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
 "runtimeArgs": [
  "run-script",
  "debug"
 ],
 "port": 9229,
 "restart": true,
 "console": "integratedTerminal"        
}
```

Comment: Check my solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732586/terminate-ng-serve-task-in-vs-code-on-stop-debugging/72981959#72981959

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the solution is to add the `--exitcrash` flag. It's working for me (at least when I initially tested it just now). So:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app",
  "debug": "nodemon --experimental-modules --inspect --exitcrash ./bin/www.mjs"
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
 "runtimeArgs": [
   "run-script",
   "debug",
   "--exitcrash"
 ],
```

I got this idea from here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56756#issuecomment-462585020

Answer (score 0):

From `launch.json` -> `runtimeExecutables` & `runtimeArgs`, it runs the command `npm run dev` (more at the bottom of the answer).

I add the solution @MattBrowne https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692376/9192954

My `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "dev",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script",
        "dev",
        "--exitcrash"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "avalanche_nft",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "Guillem Puche",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "lint": "prettier --write 'src/**' & eslint --ext .ts,.js,.json"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts & npm run lint",
    "watch": [
      "src"
    ],
    "ext": ".json,.ts,.env"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2021,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:json/recommended",
      "prettier"
    ],
    "ignorePatterns": "dist"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "semi": true,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "useTabs": false,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "printWidth": 80
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "avalanche": "^3.12.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.14.0",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

--

## Bonus

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                          /* Specify the folder for .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation files. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2021", /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h' */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using `jsx: react-jsx*`.` */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for `createElement`. This only applies when targeting `react` JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ], /* Specify multiple folders that act like `./node_modules/@types`. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true, /* Enable importing .json files */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow `import`s, `require`s or `<reference>`s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */
    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the `checkJS` option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from `node_modules`. Only applicable with `allowJs`. */
    /* Emit */
    // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    "sourceMap": true, /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If `declaration` is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    "outDir": "./dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have `@internal` in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like `__extends` in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing `const enum` declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */
    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.. */
    "strictNullChecks": true, /* When type checking, take into account `null` and `undefined`. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when `this` is given the type `any`. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Type catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    "alwaysStrict": true, /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when a local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */
    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```